# Auto-restart services on crash or close

Tags: centos, service

Today I fond that MariaDB is closed on my server (I dont know why) but its not restarted after crash.

I have already added mariadb to start on boot like:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig mariadb on
```

I want to ask that how to restart the service after it get closed ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to implement process monitoring using a tool such as [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), [god](http://godrb.com), or [bluepill](https://github.com/arya/Bluepill) among others.